# Meaning of どうすんだよ

Tags: meaning, manga

> example: "どうすんだよこの空気をよぉ！？"

Is it "What are you doing with this mood?!"? I can't make sense of it. The line is from a manga.

Answer (score 2):

'What to do about the air/atmosphere/mood?'. Without more context, it could be something other than mood, but your translation is mostly correct.

Rather than 'What are you doing with this mood', 'What will you do (What are you going to do) about this mood' would be a closer fit. As @ericfromabeno comments below, there is an implicit placing of responsibility on the listener and an urge for them to 'do something'.

This order of phrasing is very colloquial, and therefore not unusual in manga.

The use of よ and よぉ are superfluous to the actual meaning of the sentence, so let's remove them and add a comma for the pause that would normally occur:

> どうすんだ、この空気を！？

Now, it is simply a case of using grammar to define the verb, direct object, etc. and restructure the sentence into a more familiar order:

> この空気をどうすんだ！？

(どうすんだ is colloquial for どうするんですか, but I assume that you knew this).

Comment: except that "What are you doing with this mood?" and "What are you going to do about this mood?" are phrased differently enough that you can see why the questioner got confused. "What are you doing" makes it seem like the person is being asked "why" the mood occurred, while "What are you going to do" is much more clearly blaming someone and asking them to fix it.

Comment: I was going to address this, but I thought I'd leave it for a little while to see if there was any feedback or further inquiry from the OP. I'll edit presently.

Comment: So it means he did something awkward for an instance and the speaker urges the listener to take responsibility? It's weird to say something like this...

Comment: Not necessarily. Without more context it is impossible to determine why the mood is not good and if it was caused by a particular individual. Maybe provide a screenshot or surrounding dialogue?

Comment: I'm not sure how to send a picture but right before this he freaks out saying " てめぇ何赤くなってんだ！？"  the other person said something touchy about him and their friends in the other page, the speaker looks at him and he sees that his is face getting red and says these two lines

Comment: There should be an 'attach image' icon in the options when you edit your post. Anyway, it sounds like what the speaker means by 'changing the mood' is de-escalating a tense situation.