# Another use of particle "wo"?

Tags: particle-を, anastrophe

> 君の目が貫いた　僕の胸を真っ直ぐ

This is one of the lines in a song I recently heard.

I was confused why the particle "wo" is in between the direct object and an adverb that modifies the verb, 貫いた.

Can anyone explain what is going on in the sentence? Does it only apply on Written Japanese?
Thanks in advance! ^~^

Here's the [Lyrics](https://www.jpopasia.com/masakisuda/lyrics/394397/love/machigai-sagashi-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%95%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97/)

Comment: `Does it only apply on Written Japanese?` -- I think it more often occurs in casual speech. eg [どうすんだよこの空気をよぉ？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60791/9831)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Please add a link to the [original lyrics](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a05c7bf/l04bac0.html), or at least provide several lines around this. Otherwise, no one can tell if 僕の胸 is really the object of 貫いた, since lyrics usually have no punctuation marks.)

This 僕の胸 is indeed the object of 貫いた placed *after* the verb. It's semantically the same as 君の目が僕の胸を真っ直ぐ貫いた, but looks more dramatic and poetic.

This is a common rhetorical device called 倒置法. Similar things [happen also in English](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/anastrophe-famous-examples-in-literature-and-speech.html), but this is more common in the Japanese language because it does not rely much on the word order thanks to the particles.

Related:

- [Still learning Japanese and I need help with this phrase "誰が止めるというの　心が叫んだ声を"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62379/5010)
- [What does と mean in 「ここにおいで」と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38645/5010)

Comment: Thanks for the input! Here's the link btw :) https://www.jpopasia.com/masakisuda/lyrics/394397/love/machigai-sagashi-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%95%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97/

Comment: Also happens in English, this thing. You do that when you talk too, you may not even realize. Just like how Yoda talks, this is. "Inverse your sentences, you must." -- Probably Yoda